# Update query executed successfully but data is not updated in java

Tags: java, mysql, model-view-controller

My Code works correctly but the data is not updating in database. I'm using MySQL Database please find my code in attached image. Please help me if anything more required.
[image]
case 5:

```
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter roll no You Want to update");
int rollno = sc1.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter Student update Name: ");
String name = sc1.next();
System.out.println("Enter Student update Address: ");
String address = sc1.next();
updateStudent(name,rollno,address);

break;
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your code here as text

Comment: *My Code works correctly but the data is not updating in database* - well I guess it is not working correctly?

Comment: Your code never throws a `StudentException`

Comment: please see attached screen shot as link I'm not able to put whole code in comment it does not allow me to do. Thanks

Comment: Can you show snippet where you create Connection? Is it possible, that you set auto-commit false?

Comment: Dont put code in comments: edit your question and replace the screenshots with the code as text

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with your index in prepared statement.

rollno must be index 3

```
pst.setString(1,name);
pst.setString(2,address);
pst.setInt(3,rollno);
```

Comment: Thanks now it is working

Comment: @ShivkumarDubey You are welcome

Comment: can you please explain why the exception will not work for this case?

Comment: Maybe you do not get an exception. What is the content of your variables?

Comment: I just wanted to know that if you know please help me ; I'm using switch case and in switch case if any case does not matched it throw an exception.(after running my program system asking for your choice and i'm directly hitting enter button). how can I restrict the user if user directly putting enter without entering value ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at com.cg.client.Client.main(Client.java:39)

Comment: @ShivkumarDubey Sorry can't get you

Comment: Consider I'm writing switch case it will display options on console as 1. Add user 2. Delete user and suppose I'm the user who interact through console so I will be able to see this above 2 options but I'm not interested to press 1 or 2 I'm directly press enter without putting valid or invalid number so how can I prevent it throwing exception and tell the user to please enter value then hit enter do not directly hit enter after running program. Please let me know if you understand my question.

Comment: read a char and check if it is 1 or 2

Comment: That's fine but I'm more interested to know if I directly run the program and systems will ask me to choose 1 or 2 but I'm directly hitting enter button and it is throwing exception I have added in above comment see please.

Comment: @ShivkumarDubey That's why you use nextInt(). Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.util.regex.Pattern)